# How to display only alphanumeric characters in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm looking to strip out any characters that aren't A-Z a-z or 0-9.

Comment: Have you considered a regular expression?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to do this in Crystal w/ a regular expression. Would you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set some code in the display string to basically white-list characters. Went about this as follows:

```
stringvar input := {report.field};
stringvar output := '';
numbervar i;

input := Trim(input);

for i := 1 to Length(input) Step 1 do

  // 0-9 is 48-57
  // A-Z is 65-90
  // a-z is 97-122

  if (input[i] in [Chr(48),Chr(49),Chr(50),Chr(51),Chr(52),Chr(53),Chr(54),Chr(55),Chr(56),Chr(57),Chr(65),Chr(66),Chr(67),Chr(68),Chr(69),Chr(70),Chr(71),Chr(72),Chr(73),Chr(74),Chr(75),Chr(76),Chr(77),Chr(78),Chr(79),Chr(80),Chr(81),Chr(82),Chr(83),Chr(84),Chr(85),Chr(86),Chr(87),Chr(88),Chr(89),Chr(90),Chr(97),Chr(98),Chr(99),Chr(100),Chr(101),Chr(102),Chr(103),Chr(104),Chr(105),Chr(106),Chr(107),Chr(108),Chr(109),Chr(110),Chr(111),Chr(112),Chr(113),Chr(114),Chr(115),Chr(116),Chr(117),Chr(118),Chr(119),Chr(120),Chr(121),Chr(122)]) 
  then output := output + input[i];

output
```

If anyone has a cleaner/shorter way of doing this please share!

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL Expression:

```
//{%MY_FIELD}
// Oracle syntax
REGEXP_REPLACE(TABLE.FIELD, '[^0-9]', '')
```

Comment: Gotcha - I should clarify that I'm looking to do this in the report itself, not the SQL. In this case, the code in my response is located in the Display String formula. As far as I can tell Crystal doesn't have a native function for doing a regex find and replace.

Comment: The SQL Expression will pass the REGEX to the database for processing in the query's `SELECT` clause--nice and clean.  

You could reference the SQL Expression in the other field's Display String formula.

You're right: CR doesn't have native regex support.  You could use http://sourceforge.net/projects/cruflregex.